# in easelJS is there a way to say if(object == color red) then do stuff?

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I have an interactive image i'm working on, I'm using alpha properties to detect whether a shape is selected, and then if two shapes are "linked" by a button/listener then they change color. Each shape is an object called GraphicsShape
what I'd like to do is prevent two "linked" shapes  that were already linked, from being linked again incorrectly by the user with an if statment (if object != original color ) do stuff

Or I was thinking I push these objects that are "linked into an array of arrays, where each object is in the 2nd dimension array and each set of linked objects is in the first dimension.
I tried something like

```
for (var i=0; i< ArrayofArrays.length; i++)
    for (var z=0; z< ArrayofArrays[i].length z++);
       if (ArrayOfObjects)
          // don't do stuff if an object is already in the ArrayofArrays
       else
          // run link function
```

but I had errors with it, is that correct logic though? Is that possible? Can I do an if statment with if object = color?

Answer (score 1):

just put a property on a linked object, for example `myObject.linked = true;` and then you check `if ( object.linked == true ) ... else ...`

There might be other ways to achieve what you want, but without seeing your code I'd say that this would be the easiest way, to solve this.